# What is μέγεθος referring to in Jewish War 3.4

Tags: syntax, ancient-greek, grammar-identification, josephus

In the Jewish War chapter 3.4, it says:

> μόνον [οὖν] εὑρίσκει Οὐεσπασιανὸν ταῖς χρείαις ἀναλογοῦντα καὶ **τηλικούτου πολέμου μέγεθος ἀναδέξασθαι δυνάμενον**

"He found only Vespasian a match for the tasks at hand and..." but I can't understand the grammar of the rest. It reads something like "was able to be appointed for such a great war."

- τηλικούτου πολέμου = such a great war
- μέγεθος = great
- ἀναδέξασθαι = appointed
- δυνάμενον = able

What is μέγεθος doing in this sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing the noun μέγεθος ('size,' 'magnitude') with the adjective μέγας ('great').

The verb ἀναδέχομαι means 'to take upon oneself' or 'to undertake.'

The participle δυνάμενον, like ἀναλογοῦντα, modifies Οὐεσπασιανόν.

Therefore, Vespasian is being described as '(being) able to take on the magnitude of such a great war.'